# Need help for installing coova-chilli on CentOS

Tags: installation, wifi, centos6.2

I managed to install `coova-chilli` with `freeradius` and `postgresql` via `apt-get` and `chilli`'s deb package in Ubuntu. And it works.
For a couple of days, I'm struggling to install the same in `CentOS 6.2`.
Here is what I have done:

Installed `freeradius` with `postgresql` under my directory (/path/to/my/freeradius). That works good. (Tested via radtest).
Downloaded `coova-chilli` version 1.2.9, extracted it, and I have done the following from coova extracted directory:

> ./configure --prefix=/path/to/my/coova --with-openssl
>
> make
>
> make install

After I installed it, I tried to run it:

> $ /path/to/my/coova/etc/init.d/chilli start

And I get the following:

> coova-chilli[5600]: options.c: 180: could not generate configuration (/path/to/my/coova/var/run/chilli.5600.cfg.bin), sleeping one second.

So, can anybody help me on resolving my issue?

Thanks in advance!

N.B. I tried to put this question on coova-chilli forum, but I didn't get any answer. I also fallowed some posts on this topic, but without any result.

[coova-chilli installation in ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/CoovaChilli)

[coova-chilli installation in CentOS](http://www.communig8.com/articles/78-coovachilli-test-vm-configuration-part-i-31-august-2010.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved!

On short here is what I have done:

1. downloaded CoovaChilli 1.2.9 and extracted it.
2. In the extracted directory, I have done: `./configure --prefix=/my/prefix --with-openssl && make && make install`
3. edited the `/my/prefix/etc/init.d/chilli` and instead of `$(which start-stop-daemon)` I put `$(which start-stop-daemon 2>/dev/null)` [details here](http://www.communig8.com/articles/78-coovachilli-test-vm-configuration-part-i-31-august-2010.html)
4. configured `/my/prefix/etc/chilli/config` how it needed [more details here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/CoovaChilli)
5. finally, after a long struggle, I followed another one's 'thought', and I got it working: I created the `/my/path/var` directory, where I put a symbolic link to `/var/run`, called also `run` [details here](http://www.coova.org/node/4950)

All the best!